# Обособление определения

Tags: пунктуация, определения

> Племянник, в грязной европейской одежде из полотна, с громадным
>   колтуном чёрной вьющейся шерсти на голове, перетаскивал корзины с
>   плодами в глубину лавки, морщась от дыма папиросы, прилепленной к его
>   нижней кубе.

Определение к слову племянник "в грязной европейской одежде из полотна, с громадным..." обособлено потому что подразумевает значение статуса (мать, отец, дядя)? Или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существительные со значением родства действительно имеют о**граниченную сочетаемость** с определениями (согласованными и несогласованными), поэтому этот фактор можно поставить на первое место.

Но даже если определяемое слово было бы выражено  другим существительным,  определение всё равно бы обособлялось **в силу своей распространенности:**

Рабочий, **в грязной европейской одежде из полотна, с громадным колтуном чёрной вьющейся шерсти на голове**, перетаскивал корзины с плодами в глубину лавки, морщась от дыма папиросы, прилепленной к его нижней кубе.

Сравнить:

**Племянник**, в грязной рубахе, перетаскивал корзины с плодами в глубину лавки.

**Рабочий** в грязной  рубахе перетаскивал корзины с плодами в глубину лавки.